Why Am I getting an incomplete type error here?
I was wondering if someone could help me out with understanding this compiler warning?
notifier.hpp
#ifndef HAL_NOTIFIER_HPP
#define HAL_NOTIFIER_HPP

#include <any>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

#include "notification_id.hpp"
#include "notify_handle_fwd.hpp"

namespace hal
{

class notifier : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    virtual ~notifier() = default;

    virtual void register_handler(
        notification_id id, const std::shared_ptr<const notify_handle>& handler) = 0;

    virtual void notify(notification_id id) const = 0;

    virtual void notify(notification_id id, const std::any& data) const = 0;
};

}

#endif

notifier_mock.hpp
#ifndef HAL_NOTIFIER_MOCK_HPP
#define HAL_NOTIFIER_MOCK_HPP

#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include <hal/notifier.hpp>

namespace hal
{

class notifier_mock : public notifier
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(
        void,
        register_handler,
        (
            notification_id id,
            const std::shared_ptr<const notify_handle>& handler
        ),
        (override));

    MOCK_METHOD(void, notify, (notification_id id), (const, override));

    MOCK_METHOD(
        void,
        notify,
        (notification_id id, const std::any& data),
        (const, override));
};

}

#endif

I get the following error:
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:1003:14: error: base class has incomplete type
[build]  1003 |     : public __is_constructible_impl<_Tp, const _Tp&>
[build]       |       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:1010:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<testing::Matcher<const std::any &>>' requested here
[build]  1010 |     : public __is_copy_constructible_impl<_Tp>
[build]       |              ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:3205:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::is_copy_constructible<testing::Matcher<const std::any &>>' requested here
[build]  3205 |     is_copy_constructible<_Tp>::value;
[build]       |     ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/any:188:20: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_copy_constructible_v<testing::Matcher<const std::any &>>' requested here
[build]   188 |               enable_if_t<is_copy_constructible_v<_VTp>
[build]       |                           ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/any:190:7: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _Tp = const testing::Matcher<const std::any &> &, _VTp = _Decay_if_not_any<const Matcher<const any &> &>, _Mgr = _Manager<_Decay_if_not_any<const Matcher<const any &> &>>]
[build]   190 |       any(_Tp&& __value)
[build]       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]   191 |       : _M_manager(&_Mgr::_S_manage)
[build]       |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]   192 |       {
[build]       |       ~
[build]   193 |         _Mgr::_S_create(_M_storage, std::forward<_Tp>(__value));
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]   194 |       }
[build]       |       ~
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:971:54: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'any' [with _Tp = const testing::Matcher<const std::any &> &, _VTp = (no value), _Mgr = (no value), $3 = (no value)]
[build]   971 |     : public __bool_constant<__is_constructible(_Tp, _Args...)>
[build]       |                                                      ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:978:16: note: (skipping 5 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
[build]   978 |       : public __is_constructible_impl<_Tp, _Args...>
[build]       |                ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/tuple:1093:53: note: in instantiation of template type alias '_ImplicitCtor' requested here
[build]  1093 |                _ImplicitCtor<true, const _U1&, const _U2&> = true>
[build]       |                                                            ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/tuple:1095:2: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _U1 = testing::Matcher<hal::notification_id>, _U2 = testing::Matcher<const std::any &>]
[build]  1095 |         tuple(const tuple<_U1, _U2>& __in)
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]  1096 |         noexcept(__nothrow_constructible<const _U1&, const _U2&>())
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]  1097 |         : _Inherited(static_cast<const _Tuple_impl<0, _U1, _U2>&>(__in)) { }
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/tuple:981:11: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'tuple' [with _U1 = testing::Matcher<hal::notification_id>, _U2 = testing::Matcher<const std::any &>, $2 = (no value)]
[build]   981 |     class tuple<_T1, _T2> : public _Tuple_impl<0, _T1, _T2>
[build]       |           ^
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1282:7: note: while declaring the implicit copy constructor for 'MockSpec<void (hal::notification_id, const std::any &)>'
[build]  1282 | class MockSpec {
[build]       |       ^
[build] /Users/usr/Documents/Development/C++ Workspace/Code/project/test/flutter/hal/notifier_mock.hpp:27:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'testing::internal::MockSpec<void (hal::notification_id, const std::any &)>' requested here
[build]    27 |     MOCK_METHOD(
[build]       |     ^
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:115:3: note: expanded from macro 'MOCK_METHOD'
[build]   115 |   GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL(GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_, __VA_ARGS__) \
[build]       |   ^
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:49:7: note: expanded from macro 'GMOCK_PP_VARIADIC_CALL'
[build]    49 |       GMOCK_PP_CAT(_Macro, GMOCK_PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__))
[build]       |       ^
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:5:30: note: expanded from macro 'GMOCK_PP_CAT'
[build]     5 | #define GMOCK_PP_CAT(_1, _2) GMOCK_PP_INTERNAL_CAT(_1, _2)
[build]       |                              ^
[build] note: (skipping 2 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:133:3: note: expanded from macro 'GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_ARG_4'
[build]   133 |   GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL(                                         \
[build]       |   ^
[build] /Users/usr/.conan/data/gtest/1.15.0/_/_/package/3ea503d9480b6fa55c88f393c25d3db9ad78ebd5/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:192:59: note: expanded from macro 'GMOCK_INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_IMPL'
[build]   192 |   ::testing::MockSpec<GMOCK_PP_REMOVE_PARENS(_Signature)> gmock_##_MethodName( \
[build]       |                                                           ^
[build] <scratch space>:75:1: note: expanded from here
[build]    75 | gmock_notify
[build]       | ^
[build] orangepi_zero3_sysroot/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/type_traits:970:12: note: definition of 'std::__is_constructible_impl<testing::Matcher<const std::any &>, const testing::Matcher<const std::any &> &>' is not complete until the closing '}'
[build]   970 |     struct __is_constructible_impl
[build]       |            ^
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] make[3]: *** [test/unit/flutter/hal/location/CMakeFiles/unit_flutter_hal_location_tests.dir/gps_impl_tests.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [test/unit/flutter/hal/location/CMakeFiles/unit_flutter_hal_location_tests.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make[1]: *** [test/unit/flutter/hal/location/CMakeFiles/unit_flutter_hal_location_tests.dir/rule] Error

An interesting thing is this compiles fine with apple clang.
This fails when using LLVM clang when cross compiling to aarch64 using a sysroot that contains gcc12.
I can't work out what the problem is. This seems somewhat similar(ish): https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/2129

Can you please give a full example, including the two missing header files and reduce it as far as possible? For example, are all of the methods actually necessary to produce the issue? Best would be an example constructed at https://godbolt.org/, it supports Google Test.

This is an issue that has already been reported at https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2616. If their analysis is correct, then this was a defect in the C++ standard that has been fixed for C++23 as defect report. Newer standard library implementation versions should then work once this is implemented.

As you can see here libc++ hasn't implemented it yet (search for LWG3121) and I assume since it isn't listed here at all, that libstdc++ also hasn't implemented it yet. Of course I can't tell what Apple did in their standard library implementation.

@user17732522 great link, I couldn't find that issue when I was searching.

@av4625 It is a defect report, meaning that it is intended to apply to all C++ versions, but formally it was added only to C++23 (because ISO considers previous standard revisions withdrawn and replaced by the new ones and they can't formally be fixed anymore). So it shouldn't matter whether you compile for C++23 or C++17, but you need a new enough version of the standard library implementation, which currently doesn't seem to exist.

Good job on posting the full error message. I can see how one could get lost in that mess. I would, though, point out that the one of the notes links to your code: "in instantiation of template class 'testing::internal::MockSpec<void (hal::notification_id, const std::any &)>". That is, the important method has the signature void (hal::notification_id, const std::any &), i.e. the second notify method. (Also, "notifier_mock.hpp:27:5" means notifier_mock.hpp line 27, which also identifies which method to keep.) You should be able to drop the other methods from your example.

@user17732522 yes sorry, I read it wrong initially, I realise it is a bug that is to be fixed in C++23, rather than a feature coming in C++23.

@JaMiT (and everyone) sorry I definitely could/should have been a bit clearer up front saying it was the function with std::any as a param. Sorry about that!

Once you know the problem is std::any, you get to simplify to make it easier to see what's relevant, perhaps #include <any> #include <gmock/gmock.h>
struct notifier {
virtual void notify(const std::any& data) = 0;
};
and struct notifier_mock : public notifier {
MOCK_METHOD(void, notify, (const std::any& data), (override));
};. If that's all in one code block, it's easier for others to copy-compile.
